# How can I set up a continuation of my Do...While... Loop (VBA)?

Tags: string, vba, loops, concatenation

Right now, I'm just displaying a message box that will show a file name (example here is PrettyPonies), a hyphen, and a suffix starting at 001,002,003...etc. The method recommended for the suffixes works great up until it hits "010" at which point it displays "0010" because of the way it is set up. To remedy this, I want to create 2 sets of Do...While Loops as follows:

```
Sub IntegerTestforSuffixFinder()

Dim i As Double
Dim NameStr As String
Dim LengthMeasure As Integer

NameStr = "PrettyPonies"
LengthMeasure = Len(NameStr)

    Do While i < 9
    i = i + 1
        If vbOK Then
   '3-character string created by using the Right() function
   MsgBox Right(NameStr + "-" + "00" & i, LengthMeasure + 4)
        Else: End
        End If

    Do While i > 10 And i < 99
    i = i + 1
        If vbOK Then
    MsgBox Right(NameStr + "-" + "0" & i, LengthMeasure + 4)
        Else: End
        End If

Loop
Loop

End Sub
```

However, I know I'm missing something in between the loops to make it continue on to the second set. I've tried making it a whole different sub and tried saying things like Continue or Then to no avail. The program just exits the sub after it hits 009.

How can I combine my loops so that it will count up to 99?

Comment: change `Do While i > 10 And i < 99` to `Do While i >= 10 And i < 99`. Btw, why not use single loop `Do While i < 99` and use `MsgBox NameStr & "-" & Right("00" & i, 3)`?

Comment: No luck, same result :(

Comment: see my updated comment above

Comment: Um because I didn't know that would work! I'm still very new to VBA. That works perfectly, thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code with single loop:

```
Sub IntegerTestforSuffixFinder()

    Dim i As Double
    Dim NameStr As String
    Dim LengthMeasure As Integer

    NameStr = "PrettyPonies"
    LengthMeasure = Len(NameStr)

    Do While i < 99
        i = i + 1
        If vbOK Then
            '3-character string created by using the Right() function
            MsgBox NameStr & "-" & Right("00" & i, 3)
        Else: Exit Sub
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Btw, don't use `Else: End`, use `Else: Exit Sub` instead.

One more thing, since `vbOK` is equals to `1`, your `Else` part never evaluates. In your real code you could use something like this:

```
If MsgBox("Any Question", vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then
```

Answer (score 1):

Your skipping 10 because your testing for when `i` is greater than 10.  Also, your never incrementing from 9 to 10.  To fix the current implementation try this:

```
Sub IntegerTestforSuffixFinder()

Dim i As Double
Dim NameStr As String
Dim LengthMeasure As Integer

NameStr = "PrettyPonies"
LengthMeasure = Len(NameStr)

    Do While i < 9
    i = i + 1
        If vbOK Then
   '3-character string created by using the Right() function
   MsgBox Right(NameStr + "-" + "00" & i, LengthMeasure + 4)
        Else: End
        End If
    Loop

i = i + 1
    Do While i >= 10 And i < 99
        If vbOK Then
           MsgBox Right(NameStr + "-" + "0" & i, LengthMeasure + 4)
        Else: End
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

---

To simplify your implementation try this:

```
Sub MyCounter()
    Dim i As Double
    Dim NameStr As String
    Dim LengthMeasure As Integer
    Dim leadingZero As String

    NameStr = "PrettyPonies"
    LengthMeasure = Len(NameStr)

    For i = 1 To 99 Step 1
        If i > 9 Then leadingZero = "0" Else leadingZero = "00"

        MsgBox Right(NameStr + "-" + leadingZero & i, LengthMeasure + 4)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:`

```
Do While i < 100
    i = i + 1
    Debug.Print "XXX" & "-" & Format(i, "000")

Loop
```